# How do I decode a JSON String to get at a single property

Tags: php

The string looks like this.

```
string(202) 
"{"_id":"2","_rev":"2-2251dd9912477d8a2b91c6fd5ce62faf","_attachments":{"creativecommons.pdf":{"content_type":"text/pdf","revpos":2,"digest":"md5-AyV8c76dsfqfGF1BBdQIIw==","length":280357,"stub":true}}} `
```

I guess preg_match_all is a way to do it but i do not yet know the syntax for it. Maby there is an other way. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you built that JSON String, Its a bad idea giving a class name of `creativecommons.pdf` as that is not a valid class name when json_decoded to a PHP object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

preg_match ought to do it

syntax would be `preg_match('/length":(.*),/', $string, $array);`

preg_match will put the results into an array, so in this case:

`$array[0]` should be 'length":280357,;',

`$array[1]` should be '280357'

Comment: As its a JSON String its a lot easier to `json_decode()` it and use array or object notation on it. _edit: Not my downvote_ Guys its a bit rough to DV a guy with 1 rep

Comment: This is definitely the wrong way to do it. Do not use a Regex for decoding a JSON encoded string.

Comment: you're right, although at least he now knows the syntax for preg_match for next time he needs it, as he said he didn't know it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your string is a JSON string. "Prettified" it looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "2",
    "_rev": "2-2251dd9912477d8a2b91c6fd5ce62faf",
    "_attachments": {
        "creativecommons.pdf": {
            "content_type": "text/pdf",
            "revpos": 2,
            "digest": "md5-AyV8c76dsfqfGF1BBdQIIw==",
            "length": 280357,
            "stub": true
        }
    }
}
```

You can use `json_decode($JSONstring, true);` to make it a multidimensional array:

```
$decoded = json_decode($JSONstring, true);
$myLengthValue = $decoded['_attachments']['creativecommons.pdf']['length'];
echo $myLengthValue; //Returns 280357
```